# break line in locale text used in components vue

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js, internationalization, locale

I am using locales for texts in my vue app and these texts need to have break lines in the in certain places. I have tried `\n\` and `<br>` tags but they don't work. How can I go about breaking locale i18n text lines and use them in my components?

For example, the following text should go to a new line after "home is" and "heart is or"

locales/en.json:

```
"description": {
   "home": "home is \n where the heart is or <br> another random cliche sentence here"
}
```

components/hello.vue:

```
<div> {{$t("description.home")}}</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the v-html directive to show it:

```
<div v-html="description.home"></div>
```